# Fedora 14 Repository List

Tags: yum, fedora

I've got a machine running FC14 and trying to set up yum on it without much luck. I'm aware that the FC14 repo's have all gone archive though it's not possible to upgrade this box as it's an appliance (network switch) and I need to get package management running on it.

I'd tried creating a fedora.repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ with multiple options but haven't had any luck. Can I use a later repo with FC14?

My current repo file
    name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
    baseurl=http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/x86_64/os/

Can someone point me in the right direction - pulling my hair out here. Running yum update on this just sits there.

Comment: STOP what you're doing right now. If that `yum` command succeeds in making any changes to your system, you will almost certainly wind up with a brick! Upgrading to newer Fedora releases via this method, prior to F18, was not really supported, and often broke.

Comment: Stopped it before posting- thanks for letting me know. I'm just trying to get package management running on this thing so I can use it.

Comment: I wish you luck. If it really is some sort of appliance, the vendor should be supporting it.

Comment: The vendor have removed the repo files to make it difficult to install software on this thing though they give full root shell access. It's a real pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very strange situation. It's really quite bizarre that any vendor would base a "network switch" on Fedora; with its very short 13-month lifecycle it would be very difficult to support. Unless, of course, they made it impossible to install or update anything, which they seem to have done. And that opens you up to security holes...

So if you want to get to a point where you can install software on it, this is what I would recommend.

First, the official Fedora archive site is `https://archive.fedoraproject.org/`. There you will find the old repositories you are looking for.

What I would do is to [download the `fedora-release` RPM](https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/fedora-release-14-1.noarch.rpm) from Fedora 14, and apply that. Then you will have files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` which you will have to manually update their `baseurl`s to point to the appropriate directories on archive.fedoraproject.org (and remove the `mirrorlist` or `metalink` that might have been in there). This should get you to the point where you can install software and apply whatever updates were available for F14.

Also keep in mind that after you do this, the vendor is probably going to tell you to get stuffed...if they're even still in business. Which seems doubtful, if they were making silly business decisions like this.

I wouldn't even think about upgrading it past F14 unless you are prepared to sacrifice whatever functionality the vendor provided with this device. Binary compatibility with their custom software cannot be guaranteed if you upgrade to F15 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply here mate - it does seem as if they're trying to make it very difficult, see the output from trying the fedora-release package - it conflicts with one of theirs! bash-4.1# rpm -i fedora-release-14-1.noarch.rpm
warning: fedora-release-14-1.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 97a1071f: NOKEY
 file /etc/issue from install of fedora-release-14-1.noarch conflicts with file from package Eos-release-3:4.13.0-1648210.4132F.2.i686
 file /etc/issue.net from install of fedora-release-14-1.noarch conflicts with file from package Eos-release-3:4.13.0-1648210.4132F.2.i686

Comment: Ah! The vendor just got back to me with instructions on how to remove their "Lockout" RPM and get the box working properly! Thanks for the hand!

Comment: They legally have to replace the fedora-release package with their own conflicting package in order to distribute Fedora with any software that isn't included with Fedora (such as their own), according to the Fedora trademark guidelines. So I'm not surprised that it was there.