# FC14 and yum dependancies

Tags: yum, perl, fedora

I've got my hands on an FC14 machine and I've been trying to get yum working on it over the past couple of days. The machine (which is an appliance) shipped with a conflicting package to fedora-release and has taken a few days to get yum running on it. I've got yum working now but am getting a whole host of dependancy issues when I try to install something. Output here:

```
1:net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-1648306.4132F.2.i686 has missing requires of perl(Sys::Hostname)
1:net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-1648306.4132F.2.i686 has missing requires of perl(Term::ReadLine)
1:net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-1648306.4132F.2.i686 has missing requires of perl(strict)
1:net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-1648306.4132F.2.i686 has missing requires of perl(vars)
```

This goes on for many of these Perl(*) requirements and for a few other packages. I'm trying to get gcc and automake on this box. How do I clean up yum and I'm guessing theres and issue with perl here... any ideas?

Comment: Didn't we go over this [three days ago](http://serverfault.com/q/576088/126632)?

Answer (score 3):

Fedora 14 is now unsupported. You can't install or use repositories because since it is unsupported. There are no more repos and updates for Fedora 14.

You have three options: upgrade to the newest Fedora, migrate to CentOS, or try to compile what you need (I think the last way is a dead end).

The Fedora project only supports the last two versions of the OS. The versions that are supported now are 19 and 20.

Comment: Fedora 14 has been unsupported for well over two years, really.

Comment: Understood - This box is a network switch which has proprietary software from the manufacturer which only supports FC14. The box ships with FC14 and it's not possible to upgrade or reinstall anything. I'm trying to get node.js running on this thing and need to install dependancies. I wish I could upgrade - I'm in the archive repo's atm.